# Is the current page the base url?

Tags: javascript

I need to see if the current page a user is on is the main page of the website, i.e. there is nothing after the base url.

I'm doing this to exclude some code off the main page.

Comment: Note that, although it is possible to do that in JS, it is not necessarily a good idea if you want to prevent users to run certain parts of your JS. JS runs on the client, so the user has complete control over it and can change it as he/she wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (location.pathname=="/"){
  // at the root of the site
}
```

Read more on the (cross-browser) [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object.

**Edit**: If your 'root' maybe served by some file named `index` (e.g. `index.html`, `index.php`, `index.asp`, etc.) you may want:

```
var rootPattern = /^\/(?:index\.[^.\/]+)?$/i;
if (rootPattern.test( location.pathname )){
  // …
}
```

or more explicitly:

```
switch(location.pathname){
  case '/':
  case '/index.html':
  case '/index.php':
  case '/index.asp':
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (location.pathname == "/" || location.pathname == "/index.html" || location.pathname == "/index.php"){
  // at the "main page" of the site
}
```

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp

Comment: Or more tersely: `switch(location.pathname){ case '/': case '/index.html': case '/index.php': … }`